# How do i know what characters exist in my string and then count their occurrence?

Tags: java, string

I have this string ***string="aaaaaaaaadddsssaaakkaaaaand"*** i need to know what characters in it and count their occurrence ,I found this code in **stackOverFlow** but it's not helping because i need to count characters without asking the user to enter one .

```
public static int countOccurrences(String haystack, char needle)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++)
    {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle)
        {
             count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

i need a way to know that there is 5 a's and 4 v's and so on .

Comment: This looks like homework. Instead of looking and asking for a solution, try to find one yourself. I'm sure you were introduced to data structures and collections before you were asked to sole this problem.

Comment: Why do people always forget about character sets ?

Comment: Definitely a homework! Maybe we start a SE sister project titled "I am lazy, so do it for me!"? :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> countOccurrences(String haystack)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> count = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = haystack.charAt(i);
        Integer charCount = count.get(c);
        if(charCount == null) {
            count.put(c, 1);
        } else {
            count.put(c, charCount + 1);
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: You've declared your method as returning an int, but are actually returning a `Map<Char, Integer>`.  That might make it not work.

Comment: @DonRoby: Thanks, fixed, actually Keppil suggested an edit. My brain organic compiler failed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to get the counts of ALL characters in the String?  If so, a class like this might work:

```
public class CharCounter {

  private final int[] counts = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE];

  public CharCounter(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      counts[input.charAt(i)] += 1;
    }
  }

  public int getCount(char c) {
    return counts[c];
  }
}
```

To use it, you'd do something like this:

```
CharCounter counter = new CharCounter("hello world");
System.count.println("number of 'l' characters: " + counter.getCount('l'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to GIVE you the code answer, but this different idea should get you started:

1. You need to have an empty array (or arrayList) of characters, and an empty String, and of
   course, your "to be counted" string (haystack).
2. use a sorting method to go through the haystack and sort it
   **alphabetically** (go look this up, it's not really too hard).
3. Once you have sorted it alphabetically, do another for loop that goes through the new,
   alphabetically sorted string, and **add** a new character to the empty array of characters
   if the character at position i+1 is not the same as the one before it. Now, at the end of
   this loop, that array of characters will have a small list of the DIFFERENT letters in
   your original String!
4. yet ANOTHER for loop... this is the last one. This time, it's going to be a for loop
   inside a for loop. The outer for loop will go through your new array of characters, and the inner one will cycle through the characters of your original String. Now, you can count how many times in your String the first character in the array of characters comes, then the second, third, fourth.... etc. Each time, You can print out "5 a's" "6 b's" etc.

This should work. Let me know!